# parsing message to, from and subject

Tags: python, email, imap

I'm trying to fetch unread messages from IMAP. When I'm trying to parse email content I get `len(email_message.keys()) == 0`. So that I never get `From`, `To` and `Subject`.

Printed email (`email.message_from_string(email_str)`):

```
From nobody Fri Sep 14 13:42:50 2012

1 (RFC822 {1015}
Return-Path: <sender@domain.com>
X-Original-To: recepient@domain.com
Delivered-To: recepient@domain.com
Received: from ec2.....amazonaws.com (unknown [IP])
    (Authenticated sender: sender@domain.com)
    by domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id EACD436CF
    for <recepient@domain.com>; Fri, 14 Sep 2012 12:47:54 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: ....
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: sender@domain.com
To: recepient@domain.com
Subject: welcome

Dear recipient,

Welcome.

Best,
Robot
```

And here's the code:

```
def fetch_new_emails(host, port, user, password):
  conn = imaplib.IMAP4(host=host, port=port)

  try:
    (retcode, capabilities) = conn.login(user, password)
    conn.select(readonly=1) # Select inbox or default namespace
    (retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
    results = []
    if retcode == 'OK':
      for message in messages[0].split(' '):
        (ret, raw_email) = conn.fetch(message, '(RFC822)')
        if ret == 'OK':
          print raw_email[0]
          email_str = string.join(raw_email[0], "\n")
          email_message = email.message_from_string(email_str)
          email_from = email_message['From']
          to = email_message['To']
          subject = email_message['Subject']
          results.append({
            'from': email_from, 
            'to': to,
            'subject': subject})
  except:
    print sys.exc_info()[1]
    sys.exit(1)
  finally:
    conn.close()
  return results
```

The problem:

```
print email_message['From']
>>None    
print email_message['To']
>>None
print email_message['Subject']
>>None
```

Comment: Can you print out just the raw_email response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a weird empty line after the `From nobody...` line. Technically an empty line is the end of headers, and everything after that is body, so the message really doesn't have those headers.

Anyway, an IMAP message should not have a `From` line (this is typical of Berkeley mbox format, which few IMAP servers use; and even if yours does, this detail of its storage implementation should not be visible to IMAP clients).

The weird `1 (RFC822 {1015}` line doesn't belong, either; it looks vaguely like part of an IMAP protocol response, not part of the actual message. The message proper starts with the `Return-Path:` header in this particular case.

Is the IMAP server and/or the client code not production versions?

Comment: Indeed, this is part of the IMAP Protocol: ``1 (RFC822 {1015}``.  In fact, that's the response imaplib will give you to FETCH. Message sequence number 1, RFC822 response, 1015 bytes following.  The next part of the response is the actual message.